# CURL fails after many runs saying "could not establish connection" or "connect() timed out"

Tags: php, curl, timeout, remote-server

I'm trying to index many hundrets of web-pages.

## In Short

1. Calling a PHP script using a CRON-job
2. Getting some (only around 15) of the least recently updated URLs
3. Querying theses URLs using CURL

## The Problem

In development everything went fine. But when I started to index much more then some testpages, CURL refused to work after some runs. It does not get any data from the remote server.

## Error messages

These errors CURL has printed out (of course not at once)

1. couldn't connect to host
2. Operation timed out after 60000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

I'm working on a V-Server and tried to connect to the remote server using Firefox or wget. Also nothing. But when connecting to that remote server from my local machine everything works fine.

Waiting some hours, it again works for some runs.

For me it seems like a problem on the remote server or a DDOS-protection or something like that, what do you guys think?

Comment: also take a look at the http error codes

Comment: The http status code is always 0 when failing

Comment: What do you mean by connecting via wget/FF vs. connecting from your local machine? What is the difference?

Comment: I mean that if curl stops working, it can't be a PHP or curl problem, because my whole V-Server (not only curl but also wget/FF) is unable to connect to the remote server.

Comment: But when browsing the remote site with my local browser everything works fine - which means the remote server is not offline. Also running the script on my local apache server works for a while. Interesting: in my opinion (I did not measure it yet!) when experiencing the failure on my local machine, it does take less time until it works again. (Edit: no, it can't be because the IP of my local machine changed in the meanwhile; I have fix IP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using proxies when you send out too many requests as your IP can be blocked by the site by their DDOS protection or similar setups.

Here are somethings to note : (What I used for scraping datas of websites)

1.Use Proxies.

2.Use Random User Agents

3.Random Referers

4.Random Delay in crons.

5.Random Delay between requets.

What I would do is make the script run for ever and add sleep in between.

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Just trigger it with visiting the url for a sec and it will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

How often is the script run? It really could be triggering some DOS-like protection. I would recommend implementing some random delay to make the requests seem delayed by some time to make them appear more "natural"

Comment: The script ran every minute, I've already changed it to 5 minutes. With every run it sends between 5 and 20 requests.

Comment: And I had a delay implemented: randomly from 1 to 5 seconds between every request. Do you think, it was too little?

Comment: it looks fine - having 20 requests every 5 minutes should be fine